# Write to existing json file in specific place

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a json file in which must be added some values which I am getting from another json file. the problem is that I could add anything at the end of the json, but not in the exact place.
My actual json file is:

```
{
  "id" : "some-id",
  "name" : "some-name",
  "email" : "some@email.com",
  "config" : {
    "pipelineConfigs" : [ {
      "application" : "service1",
      "pipelineConfigId" : "d2eb526c-839b-41b3-b59c-f86db6eebb4e"
    }, {
      "application" : "service2",
      "pipelineConfigId" : "f79394b6-e37f-42e2-a9b3-fdbcf85ad1d7"
    } ],
    "applications" : [ "service1", "service2" ],
    "clusters" : [ {
      "account" : "some-account",
      "stack" : "*",
      "detail" : "*",
      "applications" : null
    } ]
  },
  "updateTs" : 1510750871252,
  "createTs" : 1510743534340,
  "lastModifiedBy" : "admin"
}
```

I am getting `service3` and `another-id` from another json file Need to add them into destination json file in this way:

```
       {
      "application" : "service3",
      "pipelineConfigId" : "another-id"
    },
```

after this part:

```
"config" : {
    "pipelineConfigs" : [
```

and add the `"service3"` to `"applications" : [ "service1", "service2" ],`

The desired final result:

```
{
  "id" : "some-id",
  "name" : "some-name",
  "email" : "some@email.com",
  "config" : {
    "pipelineConfigs" : [ {
      "application" : "service1",
      "pipelineConfigId" : "d2eb526c-839b-41b3-b59c-f86db6eebb4e"
    }, {
      "application" : "service2",
      "pipelineConfigId" : "f79394b6-e37f-42e2-a9b3-fdbcf85ad1d7"
    }, {
      "application" : "service3",
      "pipelineConfigId" : "another-id"
    } ],
    "applications" : [ "service1", "service2", "service3" ],
    "clusters" : [ {
      "account" : "some-account",
      "stack" : "*",
      "detail" : "*",
      "applications" : null
    } ]
  },
  "updateTs" : 1510750871252,
  "createTs" : 1510743534340,
  "lastModifiedBy" : "admin"
}
```

Which direction I should dig?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*a.py*:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint as pp

def add_app(obj_dict, app_name, pipeline_config_id):
    new_cfg = {
        "application": app_name,
        "pipelineConfigId": pipeline_config_id,
    }
    obj_dict["config"]["pipelineConfigs"].append(new_cfg)
    obj_dict["config"]["applications"].append(app_name)


def main():
    with open("initial.json") as fin:
        obj = json.load(fin)
    print("INITIAL:\n")
    pp(obj)
    add_app(obj, "service3", "another_id")
    print("\nFINAL:\n")
    pp(obj)
    # EDIT: writing the modified json to file
    with open("final.json", "w") as fout:
        json.dump(obj, fout, indent="  ")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Notes**:

- I saved your initial json in a file called *initial.json* which I'm loading using the [[Python]: json — JSON encoder and decoder](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json) module
- 2 things needed to do (after loading the file):

  - Add the application name to the existing applications list
  - Ad the application config to the existing  pipeline configs list
- I'm **not** doing any error checking

**Output**:

> ```
> c:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q47345368>"c:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py35x64_test\Scripts\python.exe" a.py
> INITIAL:
>
> {'config': {'applications': ['service1', 'service2'],
>             'clusters': [{'account': 'some-account',
>                           'applications': None,
>                           'detail': '*',
>                           'stack': '*'}],
>             'pipelineConfigs': [{'application': 'service1',
>                                  'pipelineConfigId': 'd2eb526c-839b-41b3-b59c-f86db6eebb4e'},
>                                 {'application': 'service2',
>                                  'pipelineConfigId': 'f79394b6-e37f-42e2-a9b3-fdbcf85ad1d7'}]},
>  'createTs': 1510743534340,
>  'email': 'some@email.com',
>  'id': 'some-id',
>  'lastModifiedBy': 'admin',
>  'name': 'some-name',
>  'updateTs': 1510750871252}
>
> FINAL:
>
> {'config': {'applications': ['service1', 'service2', 'service3'],
>             'clusters': [{'account': 'some-account',
>                           'applications': None,
>                           'detail': '*',
>                           'stack': '*'}],
>             'pipelineConfigs': [{'application': 'service1',
>                                  'pipelineConfigId': 'd2eb526c-839b-41b3-b59c-f86db6eebb4e'},
>                                 {'application': 'service2',
>                                  'pipelineConfigId': 'f79394b6-e37f-42e2-a9b3-fdbcf85ad1d7'},
>                                 {'application': 'service3',
>                                  'pipelineConfigId': 'another_id'}]},
>  'createTs': 1510743534340,
>  'email': 'some@email.com',
>  'id': 'some-id',
>  'lastModifiedBy': 'admin',
>  'name': 'some-name',
>  'updateTs': 1510750871252}
> ```

Comment: this worked for me. I also need to write FINAL back to INITIAL file.
So as I run the script and after that I open the json file, I'll see the final.
Should I use json.dumps for that?

Comment: Just added the code. Using `json.dumps` is possible (that writes to a string), but using `json.dump` it's easier. I'm writing to another file (to avoid overwriting the original content). Change the output file name to the to match the one of the input file.

Comment: This wrote to a file, but with 1 line. how to write as it was before?

Comment: Added some indenting. Note that it won't match the input _json_ from the question **exactly** ("records" like: `[ {`, `}, {`, `} ]`).

Comment: I know about matching, it;s ok. but adding the indent throws me an error "TypeError: 'indent' is an invalid keyword argument for this function"

Comment: Crap! I rushed into editing the post and end up modifying the wrong function. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've loaded the JSON files, the structures are just nested Python dictionaries and lists:

```
import json

data = '''\
{
  "id" : "some-id",
  "name" : "some-name",
  "email" : "some@email.com",
  "config" : {
    "pipelineConfigs" : [ {
      "application" : "service1",
      "pipelineConfigId" : "d2eb526c-839b-41b3-b59c-f86db6eebb4e"
    }, {
      "application" : "service2",
      "pipelineConfigId" : "f79394b6-e37f-42e2-a9b3-fdbcf85ad1d7"
    } ],
    "applications" : [ "service1", "service2" ],
    "clusters" : [ {
      "account" : "some-account",
      "stack" : "*",
      "detail" : "*",
      "applications" : null
    } ]
  },
  "updateTs" : 1510750871252,
  "createTs" : 1510743534340,
  "lastModifiedBy" : "admin"
}'''

D = json.loads(data)
other = {'application':'service3',
         'pipelineconfigId':'another-id'}

# Make the two modifications...
D['config']['pipelineConfigs'].append(other)
D['config']['applications'].append(other['application'])

data = json.dumps(D,indent=2)
print(data)
```

Output:

```
{
  "id": "some-id",
  "name": "some-name",
  "email": "some@email.com",
  "config": {
    "pipelineConfigs": [
      {
        "application": "service1",
        "pipelineConfigId": "d2eb526c-839b-41b3-b59c-f86db6eebb4e"
      },
      {
        "application": "service2",
        "pipelineConfigId": "f79394b6-e37f-42e2-a9b3-fdbcf85ad1d7"
      },
      {
        "application": "service3",
        "pipelineconfigId": "another-id"
      }
    ],
    "applications": [
      "service1",
      "service2",
      "service3"
    ],
    "clusters": [
      {
        "account": "some-account",
        "stack": "*",
        "detail": "*",
        "applications": null
      }
    ]
  },
  "updateTs": 1510750871252,
  "createTs": 1510743534340,
  "lastModifiedBy": "admin"
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark. it works. But I also need to write it to the initial file. what should I use for that?